# bad format at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, google-chrome

in connection to this post [tag info new tab is badly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62363/tag-info-new-tab-is-badly-formatted),

the following line in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery,

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions for rapid web development. 
**jQuery is designed to change the way that you write JavaScript**.

as what I think it should be, is displayed as

---

[jQuery][1] is a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions for rapid web development. 
**jQuery is designed to change the way that you write JavaScript**. [1]: http://jquery.com/

---

[image]

on my page, chrome 5.0.375.127

Comment: I think it would be a really good idea to somehow better format the tag info boxes. Currently they just look like wall-o-texts that you'd rather not read at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I part fixed this yesterday ... this issue appears for any wikis shorter than 460 chars.

I just committed a fix to dev.

Answer (score 1):

Markdown just is not interpreted in the tag info box, but changing to "about the [tag] tag" it is and will appear correctly. This is browser independent.

It would be much better if markdown were interpreted, but as it takes a substring of certain length to limit the size of the info box, formatting could blow the box up in size. Also, too much formatting could overemphasize the box. I would propose a stripped version without formatting to keep the box as little intrusive as possible.