# Tag Wiki Summary Does Not Allow Markup?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, markdown, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown seems not to work in tag information excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/markdown-seems-not-to-work-in-tag-information-excerpts)

I tried the new tag wiki tonight on the [ActiveSync tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activesync). I added some hyperlinks yet when this formatting was applied, it did not show in the tag wiki summary for the [ActiveSync tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activesync). The tag wiki uses the same markup as questions and answers so I assume this also would be permitted. It shows under '[Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/activesync/info)' instead.

Could we have the same markup show in the summary as is in the Tag Info? I doubt many people will actually click on the Tag Info link so the markup should be shown IMHO.

Comment: This is related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62371/bad-format-at-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-tagged-jquery/62372#62372

Comment: This is by design, see e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/markdown-seems-not-to-work-in-tag-information-excerpts/62218#62218).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be - as you can see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62371/bad-format-at-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-tagged-jquery/62372#62372) - that at least in some cases markup was not interpreted, but shown plain, which was very ugly. Since then formatting has been stripped in the preview box for tag wiki - to make it non-intrusive, I would guess.

Answer (score 2):

> Could we have the same markup show in
>   the summary as is in the Tag Info? I
>   doubt many people will actually click
>   on the Tag Info link so the markup
>   should be shown IMHO.

This is intentional, the excerpt is used by the tag hover and summary area. We need to keep it concise and text only so it renders well in both these formats.

See also: [Markdown seems not to work in tag information excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/markdown-seems-not-to-work-in-tag-information-excerpts)